# working with SeekBar with two thumbs

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

I've used [this link](http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-seek-bar-with-two-thumb.html) to implement **SeekBar with two thumbs** and I got the output.

But this seekbar has one issue that it allows crossing of **thumb 1** and **thumb 2** i.e. it allows thumb 1 value to be **greater than** thumb 2 value which should not be allowed as per my requirement.

What modification in following code should be performed to achieve this?

```
public class SeekBarWithTwoThumb extends ImageView {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.leftthumb);
    private int thumb1X, thumb2X;
    private int thumb1Value, thumb2Value;
    private int thumbY;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int selectedThumb;
    private int thumbHalfWidth;
    private SeekBarChangeListener scl;


    public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (getHeight() > 0)
            init();
    }

    private void init() {
        printLog("View Height =" + getHeight() + "\t\t Thumb Height :"
                + thumb.getHeight());
        if (thumb.getHeight() > getHeight())
            getLayoutParams().height = thumb.getHeight();

        thumbY = (getHeight() / 2) - (thumb.getHeight() / 2);
        printLog("View Height =" + getHeight() + "\t\t Thumb Height :"
                + thumb.getHeight() + "\t\t" + thumbY);

        thumbHalfWidth = thumb.getWidth()/2;
        thumb1X = thumbHalfWidth;
        thumb2X = getWidth()/2 ;
        invalidate();
    }
    public void setSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBarChangeListener scl){
        this.scl = scl;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,
                paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,
                paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int mx = (int) event.getX();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mx >= thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth
                    && mx <= thumb1X + thumbHalfWidth) {
                selectedThumb = 1;
                printLog("Select Thumb 1");
            } else if (mx >= thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth
                    && mx <= thumb2X + thumbHalfWidth) {
                selectedThumb = 2;
                printLog("Select Thumb 2");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            printLog("Mouse Move : " + selectedThumb);

            if (selectedThumb == 1) {
                thumb1X = mx;
                printLog("Move Thumb 1");
            } else if (selectedThumb == 2) {
                thumb2X = mx;
                printLog("Move Thumb 2");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            selectedThumb = 0;
            break;
        }

        if(thumb1X < 0)
            thumb1X = 0;

        if(thumb2X < 0)
            thumb2X = 0;

        if(thumb1X > getWidth() )
            thumb1X =getWidth() ;

        if(thumb2X > getWidth() )
            thumb2X =getWidth() ;

        invalidate();
        if(scl !=null){
            calculateThumbValue();
            scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value,thumb2Value);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void calculateThumbValue(){
        thumb1Value = (100*(thumb1X))/(getWidth());
        thumb2Value = (100*(thumb2X))/(getWidth());
    }
    private void printLog(String log){
        Log.i(TAG, log);
    }

    interface SeekBarChangeListener{
        void SeekBarValueChanged(int Thumb1Value,int Thumb2Value);
    }


}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `OnTouch` event, replace your code with below code. Hope it helps

```
    calculateThumbValue();

    if(thumb1Value < thumb2Value) {
        invalidate();
        if(scl != null){
            scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value, thumb2Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working but app is getting in ANR mode after few seconds... Any idea why?

Comment: no... I don't have any idea y its behaving like that. As thumb is bitmap, I thought its giving out of memory error